# How to assign color to pixel according to its mean value

Tags: python, image, numpy

image_copy is an RGB image.

If the average value of the three components, (R, G, B), is less than a certain value, that pixel will be white. If it is smaller I will give it the black value.

I tried with np.where and np.mean but it doesn't produce results.

```py
    imagen = io.imread('example.jpg')
    imagen_copy = imagen.copy()
    imagen_copy[np.where((np.mean(imagen_copy, axis=1) <= 58.0))] = [255,255,255]
    imagen_copy[np.where((np.mean(imagen_copy, axis=1) > 58.0))] = [0, 0, 0]
    io.imshow(imagen_copy)
    plt.show()
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it "doesn't produce results"? What result are you expecting and what result are you actually getting? Also a [mcve] might help.

Comment: If the average intensities for the position x is less than 58 I want x to be [255, 255, 255]

Comment: Now no pixel is changed to 255 or 0

Comment: You want `axis=2` or `axis=-1`.  The first two axes (0 and 1) are the rows and columns of the image.  Also, if you first change all pixels >= 58 to [255,255,255], then in the next step you're setting all the pixels to [0,0,0]

Comment: Where is the [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to take the mean along the last axis, and rather than using `np.where` for both cases the following should suffice:

```
(images.mean(-1) <= 58.0) * 255
```